# move_base vs geometry_msgs/PoseStamped md5 error, Electric, deb-install

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just been trying to run (for the first time, so maybe I just set something wrong) `move_base` together with `gmapping` on ROS Electric (on Ubuntu 10.04). As soon as `move_base` goes up, an error appears:

```
[ERROR] [1323959697.184014051]: Client [/move_base] wants topic /move_base/goal 
to have datatype/md5sum [move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal/660d6895a1b9a16dce51fbdd9a64a56b], 
but our version has [geometry_msgs/PoseStamped/d3812c3cbc69362b77dc0b19b345f8f5]. 
Dropping connection.
```

I've installed all ROS packages via apt-get. There has been some update today, so maybe some of the packages weren't rebuilt properly. Has anyone else noticed this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12354/move_base-vs-geometry_msgs/posestamped-md5-error,-electric,-deb-install/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you´re somewhere mixing the actionlib-interface of move_base with the move_base_simple topic which expects to receive a geometry_msgs/PoseStamped. Are you running rviz and setting a goal-pose for the robot with it? If so, open the Tool Properties and (View-> Tool Properties) and set 2D Nav Goal to "move_base_simple"

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-15**:
OK, thanks a lot, seems to have been it. So it's my setup, I have to read a bit more about using gmapping with move_base and rviz, I guess.

**Comment by [chbloca](https://answers.ros.org/users/38830/chbloca/) on 2019-04-09**:
Have you found a solution for this?